# Provide open sets $U_1$ $U_2$ such that the function $f(z)$ is holomorphic and has antiderivative in $U_1$ but not $U_2$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

**Provide open sets $U_1, U_2 \subset \mathbb{C}$ with $U_1 \cap U_2 \neq \emptyset$ such that the function
$$
f(z)=e^z+\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{e^{z^2}}{z-2}
$$
is holomorphic in $U_1 \cup U_2$ and such that $f$ has an antiderivative in $U_1$ but not in $U_2$. Justify your answer.**

So far I know I can check where each function is holomorphic and treat it as the addition of holomorphic functions.

i.e

$e^z$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$

$\frac{1}{z^2}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$

$\frac{-e^{z^2}}{z-2}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{2\}$

I know there is a singularity at $0$ and $2$ so neither set may contain these points as the function is holomorphic on the union of these two sets?

Comment: Discs can work for $U_1$, but not for $U_2$.

Comment: The last component of the function becomes discontinuous at z=2?

Comment: That's not it. You would never include $z=2$ itself as part of either set. The function is supposed to be holomorphic on both sets, and in particular continuous. $z=0$ is also a suspicious point. Both are poles, but $z=0$ is a pole of order $2$. So, it doesn't cause problems for $1/z^2$ to have anti-derivative around $z=0$ (on a punctured neighborhood). However, $z=2$ is a pole of order $1$.

Comment: Jami Ward, can you edit your post so that instead of "(2,4)" and "(3,5)" it has at least understandable notation?

Comment: @NBD would it be possible for you to elaborate on why z=0 doesnt cause issues? I scanned over my notes and cant find anything in relation to the order of the poles. As a hunch from your hints, am I right in saying the answer is the open balls, $U_1=B_2(0)$ and $U_2=B_1(1)$ of radius 2, and 1 respectively

Comment: The main idea is that $(z-a)^k$ has antiderivative $\frac{(z-a)^{k+1}}{k+1}$, for all $k$ except $k=-1$.  So, $k=-2$ is part of those. However, for $k=-1$ there cannot be anti-derivative on a domain that goes all the way around $z=a$. The reason is that then antiderivative exists, then integrals on closed loops are zero. But $(z-a)^{-1}$ has non-zero integral, along a circle that goes around $z=a$. So, poles of order $1$ prevent antiderivatives on domains circling the pole.

Comment: So, you should take $U_2$ to be, for example, a punctured disc with center $z=2$ and not including $z=0$. The latter condition such that the function is holomorphic. We don't want singularities inside the domain. For $U_1$ you can take any domain that doesn't include the singularities and that doesn't go around $z=2$.

Comment: @NDB I actually seen (z-a)^k having antiderivative in my notes last night, it appears I was too sleep deprived to notice, An interesting thing to remember!                            
To clarify, We can consider $U_1=D_1(1)$ as $e^z$ has antiderivative ($F(z)=e^z\forall z\in\mathbb C$),$\frac{1}{z^2}$ has antiderivative $\forall z\in\mathbb C$ (pole of order 2), I cant identify why the last part would have antiderivative? and then $U_2=D_2(2)\backslash\{2\}$ does not have antiderivative (pole of order 1)  side note, I fixed my notation to represent discs and also thanks for your patience

Comment: Also, I thought punctured discs are neither open nor closed?

Comment: The last summand is analytic on $U_1$ and $U_1$ is simply connected. So, integrals of the last summand along closed loops inside $U_1$ are zero. This allows defining an antiderivative, by fixing a point $z_0\in U_1$ and considering $F(z)=\int_{z_0}^{z}f(x)$. Any path from $z_0$ to $z$ inside $U_1$ can be used, since all give the same value of the integral, thanks to the previous observation. An open disc with the center removed is open.

Comment: @NDB thank you again for your patience! so those two sets satisfy the criteria? Apologies for having to be spoon fed, my lecturer wasn't incredibly clear when explaining material